# getting data from owl file in java

Tags: sparql, jena

i am getting all members of Student .i use the following code but i getting result only ind my query is correct .  when i run that query in protege 4.3 they give correct result but problem in java code.i dont understand what i do wrong .please suggest what i wrong in my java class.

```
class sparql1
    {  public static void main(String[] args) {

            String filename="modified2.owl";
            Model model=ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
            OntModel model1=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);

            try
            {
                File file=new File(filename);
                FileInputStream reader=new FileInputStream(file);
                model.read(reader,null);

                String query1=" PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> PREFIX my: <http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#> SELECT  ?ind WHERE { ?ind rdf:type my:Student .}";

                com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query query=QueryFactory.create(query1);
                QueryExecution exe=QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1);
                ResultSet RES=exe.execSelect();
                ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, RES, query);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

my ontology is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
    <!ENTITY untitled-ontology-10 "http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10"
     xmlns:untitled-ontology-10="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10"/>
     <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#hasAddress -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-10;hasAddress"/>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#hasEmail -->

    <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-10;hasEmail"/>
   <owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-10;Student"/>
    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#Student2 -->

  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-10;Student2">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-10;Student"/>
        <hasEmail rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">asd</hasEmail>
        <hasAddress rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">sdsad</hasAddress>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>



    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#student1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-10;student1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-10;Student"/>
        <hasEmail rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">fhgchg</hasEmail>
        <hasAddress rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">me</hasAddress>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/rohit/ontologies/2014/4/untitled-ontology-10#student3 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-10;student3">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-10;Student"/>
        <hasEmail rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">dsfdsf</hasEmail>
        <hasAddress rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">sdfds</hasAddress>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: What problem you get in the Java code?  Unexpected results?  An exception?  Please show us.  What's your ontology?  Do you use a reasoner in Protégé?  It is possible that some individuals are *inferred* to be students?  There's not enough information here to diagnose the problem yet.

Comment: my code is executed out put is only ind mean unexpected.i am use reasoner in protege.that query is executed in protege and result is show student member(i.e studnet1,student2,student3) my ontology is bellow thanks for reply

Comment: output is not getting as like (student1,student2,student3) excepted

Comment: Please include the results that you get from protege as well as the results that you get from your java code so that we can compare them.

Comment: java code output is -ind AND protege output is student2 student3 student1 thanks for reply me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no results because you are querying the empty `model1` while all of your results are contained in `model`. Simply change:

```
OntModel model1=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
```

... to ...

```
OntModel model1=ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM, model);
```

... and then your subsequent query will have access to the triples inside of the `OntModel`. The proof is found on the line where you create your `QueryExecution` instance:

```
QueryExecution exe=QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model1);
```

On this line, you create a query that references the new model, which has none of the triples that you read in from your file.